# How to specify access key for a menu item?

Tags: wpf

How to specify an access key for a menu item?

```
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Copy" Command="Copy" />
```

Per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb545460.aspx#accessKeys

Edit: I really mean [menu *access keys*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb545460.aspx#menu), not shortcut keys.

Comment: '_' inside the header makes symbol as access key, see my answer pls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use _ at the Header,This will create automatically the desired HotKey.

```
<MenuItem Header="_Copy"  
InputGestureText="Ctrl+F "/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create KeyBinding that executes the same command

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="Copy" Key="F5" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

And if you want to show command inside Menu item you can define it like this

```
<MenuItem Header="_Copy" InputGestureText="F5"/>
```

BTW, _ symbol makes the symbol near it as access key